# splitting 10 AWG to L6-30 receptacle

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, 240v

*TLDR; Can I take the (3) 10AWG THHN lines and split them to (2) L6-30 receptacles*

**Background:**
I have 240V wired in my server room (computer equipment) and currently have 10AWG THHN running from a 20AMP dual pole breaker to a L6-30 receptacle.  Im running a 20AMP breaker so that it trips well before the 10AWG wire reaches its max operating temp (since its rated for 30AMP)

My 13 port PDU is full and I'd like to add another one, but I only have a single L6-30 receptacle.

NOTE: It should be noted here before the haters start jumping all over this, the main reason the PDU is full is because most of the equipment (1/2 is low power) has redundant power supplies.  Only 1 PS is truly drawing load at a time, the other is more or less on standby.

**Question:**
With that explained: Can I take the (3) 10AWG THHN lines and split them to (2) L6-30 receptacles and be safe/in code?  I'm not looking at adding significant load to the circuit, I'll be adding another switch and other low power redundant devices.

Comment: If the breaker is properly sized for the wire (33% undersized in your case) then I don't see the issue from a safety standpoint. I cannot comment on actual code.

Comment: awesome thank you!  if there is enough room on the receptacle terminals, can I daisy chain from one receptacle to another like you see done on 120V circuits?

Comment: I don't see an issue. ["See 210.23. You can have multiple receptacles on a 30A 240V circuit, but no one item is allowed to draw more than 80% of the circuit rating in that case."](https://forums.mikeholt.com/threads/multiple-receptacles-on-240v-circuit.2554853/)

Comment: It is a code violation to have receptacles larger than 20A on a 20A circuit. Table 210.24 in NEC 2017.

Comment: This all sounds quite hacky and it seems like you could use a more vanilla installation to achieve what you want.  1) What's the total peak power consumption of all the equipment you need to power?  2) Is it all universal voltage?

Comment: @jay613 everything is 240V capable.  devices are: 1) router 2) 2 switches (150w) 3) monitor 4) WAP 5) dual R720 esxi servers (750w) 6) dual dell hb-1235 storage arrays (580w)
----------------------
total peak power consumption should be around 3250w, assuming everything is running full tilt, which it never is.

Comment: Ok, so you're using a 20A breaker and you are well within 20A capacity.   Why then are you using 30A sockets?  You could build a "PDU" with 6-20R sockets in multi-gang metal boxes and add as many of these as you want.  I wonder if this would all be cheaper than just running a couple of new 120V circuits, running everything at 120V and using off-the-shelf power bars??

Comment: @jay613 there wasnt much of a price difference between the 6-20r and 6-30r sockets and I wanted the circuit to be 30 amp capable, minus the breaker.   Since the 20A breaker isnt code, i'll be upgrading it in the near future when I split the 240v line to both receptacles.  ------  Regarding running 240v vs 120v, running 240v is always more efficient when its an option.   The main devices (servers and SAS) all prefer 240v anyway.

Comment: @jay613 also i need room for expansion in the future, this is not the final setup, more devices (servers and sas) will be added in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Background: I have 240V wired in my server room (computer equipment) and currently have 10AWG THHN running from a 20AMP dual pole breaker to a L6-30 receptacle. Im running a 20AMP breaker so that it trips well before the 10AWG wire reaches its max operating temp (since its rated for 30AMP)

Then the socket needs to be 20A.  Socket must match breaker (with a couple of exceptions, but 30A is not one of them).

> NOTE: It should be noted here before the haters start jumping all over this, the main reason the PDU is full is because most of the equipment (1/2 is low power) has redundant power supplies. Only 1 PS is truly drawing load at a time, the other is more or less on standby.

Most of us grasp this.  The only thing that's weird is *generally*, equipment takes 240V **only** because it needs more than 1500 watts. Therefore it's exceedingly bizarre to have *thirteen* 240V loads on a 20A circuit.  **Notwithstanding various small low-power devices like switches or USB hubs with 100-240V power supplies**. You can have a lot of those in any setup.

> Question: With that explained: Can I take the (3) 10AWG THHN lines and split them to (2) L6-30 receptacles and be safe/in code?

Yes. There is no limit to the number of *general purpose* receptacles on a 30A circuit.  It's just like 15-20A circuits where you can have multiple receptacles.  Does not apply to 40-50A circuits.

Since most 30A receptacles are not designed for 2 wires per terminal, you will need to pigtail.

Comment: Depending on the configuration of his PDU, he could be just fine.  Almost every power supply in the datacenters I manage is 100-250VAC auto-ranging and we supply the majority with 208 (or 240 in smaller buildings that only have single phase).  His PDU is likely loaded with IEC-320-C13 receptacles supplying 240V L-L.

Comment: @nobody. You'd never find 120V outlets on a NEMA 6 supplied device without an output transformer unless it was hacked.  That said, a LOT of IT equipment is designed such that it can be intentionally misused - especially when purchased from Amazon. :)

Comment: Whoops, brain fart. Of course a 6- plug has no neutral so it can’t supply 120V loads. IMO it seems a tad risky to have 240V on C13 sockets but I guess computer equipment almost universally accepts 90-250V nowadays.

Comment: Not too uncommon to see 240V on a C13 or C19.  At least it's not a NEMA 5 socket where somebody could walk in and unintentionally blow something up, although I have seen plenty of PDUs with NEMA 5 sockets that have had their L5 plug chopped off and an L6 put in its place.  Usually it's a long time before anybody plugs in a device that cares, too, and then it's magic smoke time.

Comment: Hopefully i'm not doing anything too janky? For a PDU i'm using a dell 1T891 which is 200-240V only. The devices that are plugging into the PDU can take anywhere from 110V-240V. I'm not rewiring anything from the 240V side and taking a single leg down to 120V. I do want to live

Comment: the low power devices are:
- router
- 2 switches
- monitor
- wireless access point -------

the switches have dual power supplies for redundancy, but draw under 150W each, assuming you have a full POE load, which neither are close to.

Comment: everything is using a IEC 14 to IEC 13 cable, nothing is using a NEMA 5-15P.

Comment: @nobody C13 is the default standard PC power socket all over the world, so it's not at all unusual to put 240V on a C13 socket - it's what a significant part of the rest of the world does for all their IT equipment.

Comment: @rigged ok yeah, that kinda stuff is fine. Real easy to fill a power strip with that little stuff that's 10 watts.

Answer (score 2):

Your current and proposed setups are both in violation of the NEC. A 20A circuit can have 15A or 20A receptacles. 30A receptacles are not allowed downstream of 20A overcurrent protection.

You can either keep the 20A breaker and switch to 20A receptacles (and appropriate PDUs) or switch to a 30A breaker and keep the 30A receptacles.

In either case, it is permitted to have multiple receptacles of the correct size on the circuit.

Comment: well thats an easy fix then I guess, swap the breaker from a 20A to a 30A.

I assume that code doesn't want you using higher Amperage capable receptacles than the breaker to prevent people from over heating the wiring?  if so that makes sense.  Doesnt apply to my case since i'm using the correct sized wiring, but i'm not going to get an exception either. =P